# reading value from context from a struct in other package in Go

Tags: go, middleware

I am **setting values in a struct** and passing that struct to a **context** as follows.

```
package client

type (
    applicationState struct{}
)

type ApplicationState struct {
    RequestID         string
    RequestParameters interface{}
    RequestPath       string
}

appState := ApplicationState{
        RequestID:         "123",
        RequestParameters: req,             // req is an interface{}
        RequestPath:       "abc/def",
}

newCtx := context.WithValue(ctx, applicationState{}, appState) // new context after passing the value
return handler(newCtx, req) // passing it to the handler, so I can read it in other interceptor
```

Now, when I try reading these values from context(modified context) **in a different package**, it comes out to be `nil`.

```
package server
type (
    applicationState struct{}
)

fmt.Println("values from context is:", ctx.Value((applicationState{}))) // the value is nil
```

I am confused what am I missing here?. What I thought passing a key value pair in a context can be read anywhere after setting the value.

Comment: `client.applicationState` is not the same type as `server.applicationState`

Comment: `applicationState` declared in a different package is different type which, in this case, constitutes a different context value key. https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_identity

Comment: @JimB is there's any way to make  `applicationState` global?. So that I can use it everywhere?.  What I assumed that I can fetch values from context everywhere after setting it in the context.

Comment: @mkopriva but is there's any way to fix it so that I can use values which were set as a key value pair in context, can be retrieved anywhere?.

Comment: @RajatSingh: start with the examples in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Context): _"Packages that define a Context key should provide type-safe accessors for the values stored using that key"_. If accessor functions are not acceptable, the docs also add _"Alternatively, exported context key variables' static type should be a pointer or interface."_

Comment: @JimB I think I found a solution, can you have a look at my answer?. Thanks

Comment: @RajatSingh, I would still recommend the documented solution using a function rather than an exported variable, even if it's only to avoid the the type assertion every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can someone please verify if this is a correct way to it?.

I think I found a solution, it may or may not be right, but it works across different packages as well.

Created a global struct, so instead of a local one.

```
package client

type ApplicationState struct {
    RequestID         string
    RequestParameters interface{}
    RequestPath       string
}

type (
    AppState struct{} // global struct
)

appState := ApplicationState{
        RequestID:         xrid,
        RequestParameters: req,
        RequestPath:       info.FullMethod,
    }

newCtx := context.WithValue(ctx, AppState{}, appState)
```

And then in the other package, import the package client, and fetch the value as it is.

```
package server

import "client"

fmt.Println(ctx.Value(client.AppState{}).(performance.ApplicationState).RequestID) // using it here
```